# extract text from image using robotframework in robocorp

Tags: robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RPA.Desktop

# *** Variables ***
# ${IMAGE_PATH}           alias:image    ChallanHandler.jpg

*** Tasks ***
Extract Text from Image

    Log    Current Working Directory: ${CURDIR}

    ${text}=   RPA.Desktop.Read Text    /home/buzzadmin/Documents/robocorp/login/ChallanHandler.jpg    timeout=20s
    Log    Extracted Text: ${text}
```

im gettingh an error while extracting the text from image

i tried to extract the text from image path which i gave in the code but im not able to extract the text. its showing error:

```
Extract Text from Image                                               | FAIL |
ValueError: No locator with name: /home/buzzadmin/Documents/robocorp/login/ChallanHandler.jpg
```

Comment: It seems your are missing `image:` before path.